# import grading worksheet (csv-file) to moodle automatically

Tags: csv, file-upload, moodle

I would like to upload the grading worksheet which is a csv file automatically to moodle. Before I have done it manually, but now I want that specific file to get uploaded scheduled, for example every 15 minutes or something like that because in that file there are always changes, new included grades.

I know I have to write a code which uploads the grading worksheet automatically to moodle, but I really don't know how to do that. How should the code look like? Where do I have to implement my code and in which part of the moodle server the csv file has to get uploaded??

Hope someone can help me! Thank you in advance.

Best regards
Jolie

Answer (score 0):

It is totally doable, but it is quite a project. If you dont know what you are doing, personally, I would hire a freelancer or an elearning company to handle this for you.

Basic steps you need to do if you want to do it yourself (you probably will have to do alot of research):

Write a moodle plug-in, probably an admin tool.

Implement a procedure to get the file from your service (how do you produce it?)

Copy the ordinary moodle functionality when uploading it manually (Look at the url of the site where you do, it tells you where in the filesystem of your moodle distribution you will find the code).

Get a cron job to do it every 15 minutes.

Comment: Hello Julian, thank you for your answer! What exactly do you mean by admin tool? What should that plug-in do? I want to use a grading worksheet which will always automatically get new grades from another software. That means I would always use the same sheet for uploading. My aim is to get the grades (students got for their tasks in external tools) to moodle. So the grades should get imported to moodle. This way with the grading worksheet seemed for me to be the best. Do you think it would be a good solution or are there alternatives?

Comment: Hmm, I think to be frank that the problem is, that you seem to not know much about the technical side of moodle. What you want to do is totally possible and you are thinking about it the right way. However, me explaining this step by step to you would be akin to holding a lecture. In short words: Plug-ins are programms you introduce into your moodle. There are several kinds. You need to develop one of these small moodle programms. This should be able to automatically read your worksheet, connect to the database and write the correct values. Then you need a time managing program. (Cron task).

Comment: Unhappily I am new in Moodle, so you are right, I am not familiar with the technical side of moodle. But I would like to learn more. You said that the ordinary moodle functionality for uploading the grading worksheet could be found in the URL, so what does it mean for my URL: http://vilh745a.cw01.contiwan.com:8090/moodle/mod/assign/view.php?id=70&plugin=offline&pluginsubtype=assignfeedback&action=viewpluginpage&pluginaction=uploadgrades ?? what exactly do I have to do for finding that code? Could you give me some advices for learning plugin development

Comment: The url, stepbystep, you have means the following:http://vilh745a.cw01.contiwan.com:8090 is your system url. /moodle/mod/assign/view.php is the data used in your moodle Installation. So go to your moodle installation. Find the mod directory, find the assign directory and view.php in that directory is your code. Everything after the questionmark are the parameters handed to your code. The simplest start to moodle development (I find) is this: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks This assumes though that you have atleast a little php experience. If not start learning php, I like codecademy.com

Comment: Hi Julian, thank you for you answers. I have a few new questions... Do you think I could do that job on my own in 2 1/2 months if I do not know technical side of moodle and if I only have basic php knowledge? I have to do this for a university project and do not have much time left.. You think it would be possible?    And I have an other question. If I would like to have a checkmark or a grade in moodle automatically directly (wihtout grading worksheet) from an other software, like jenkins. Is that possible? How?? Thank you in advance. I hope you can help me!

Comment: Hello Jolie, since you have just given a timespan, I assume you are gonna work fulltime on this. Then yes, 2 1/2 times is plenty of time to learn moodle and figure this out, assuming some basic coding knowledge. Also your second requirement is possibly, just define any php compatible API and use it upload a file to moodle (have a look at the file api), and use it to write it apprioriatly to the database.

Comment: Hi Julian, I have a question and in the Moodle community I couldn't find an answer. Hope that you can help me. Now I have a script which in which I can upload grades from an excel-file to moodle via web services API. I use the user_id, grade_value, add a comment and the assignment_id. I know that in moodle I do not have to add the course_id because course_id and assignment_id are never equal, ever id is unique, so I only use the assignment_id for my script. Problem is that the assignment_id in the URL doesn't match with the assignment_id in the database. Do you know why it is so?

Comment: I always have to look up in the database, that's t´really awkward. Do you know how I can make the assignment_id in the URL and database equal??? Hope you can help me!

Comment: The ID for an assignment in the URL is the number 6, but in the database that assignment has the id number 4. So I have to enter the number 4 in the Excel-file. But why is the number in the URL and database different? And how can I make them equal?